# css :before and :after pseudo-elements content property

Tags: css

I was trying to understand why only when content property is defined (with "" or any other text **but defined**) only than i can apply other css properties, For example if i remove the content property it's like there is no element and there is no other css properties apply, I would guess the content property is the "**`constructor`**" of the pseudo-element (:before or :after), At this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) i will quote:

> Objects inserted using the content property

**Object** as i understand are the **:before or :after** pseudo-element,

**Inserted(created)**

**Finally my question**: Although all i said until now, am i right?, If anyone can help me with better explanation than i wrote i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: You are right. The CSS 2.1 spec, which defines `:before` and `:after` (CSS3 Selectors spec just [links](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content) to it), says that the default value of the `content` property for these pseudo-elements computes to `none`, and the `none` value means that ["The pseudo-element is not generated"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The initial value of `content` is `none`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) When you don't define `content`, that value is used, and when that value is used, the pseudo-element is simply not generated at all. An empty string `""` is not the same as `none`; the empty string means "insert an empty object", whereas `none` means "don't insert anything at all".

Indeed, saying "objects inserted" is basically the same as "pseudo-elements created" or "boxes rendered", etc.