# Please explain: content:'';

Tags: css, css-content

Here is the code I have a question about

```css
.store {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.store:before, .store:after {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
}
.store:before {
  background: url(store-before.png);
  height: 23px;
  width: 54px;
  top:-3px;
  left:-3px;

}
.store:after {
  background: url(store-after.png);
  height: 20px;
  width: 41px;
  bottom:-3px;
  right:-3px;
}
```

I noticed that when the "content" is anything besides two apostrophes, the before and after images don't show up. Can somebody explain the meaning of the two apostrophes? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530671/css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-content-property

Comment: it's an empty string to fill the empty space

Comment: **Empty string** without this your pseudo styles will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two apostrophes denote a string. Two double quotes denote a string as well, which delimiter you use depends on preference and escaping needs; see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) for all the details.

If there's nothing between the two string delimiters, either `''` or `""`, then you have an empty string. If you have anything besides a string, it's some other value which may or may not be valid. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) for all the possible values for `content`. If you pass an invalid value, then like any other style declaration the browser will ignore it, and without any valid value `content` will default to `normal`, which is really `none` for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. That will prevent your pseudo-element from displaying.

Answer (score 4):

The [Generated content, automatic numbering, and lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) section of the CSS2.1 specification explains this:

> Authors specify the style and location of generated content with the :before and :after pseudo-elements. As their names indicate, the :before and :after pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content. The 'content' property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is inserted.

`content` is what is added to the page. If no `content` is specified, nothing is added to the page at all (meaning that ultimately no styling gets applied). `content: ''` adds empty string content to the page.

Answer (score 1):

To use the before and after elements, it needs to have some form of content before it will show the element, so you can use an empty string to pretend to be something there, obviously a space or empty will show nothing on the page, so you just get the rest of your css styling.

If you remove the content property then it wont show at all.

Its meant to be used for things like "..." or "read more" I imagine without having to have that in your html markup.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular code snippet is probably using it for clearing.

How ever you can use it to put repeating content next to elements like so:

```
span:before{
content:"Author: "
}
<span>Huckleberry Finn</span>
```

Will result in:

> Author: Huckleberry Finn